# Temperature increase needed to make pistons not move - where is my calculation wrong?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas

I feel like I'm missing something here.

> 2 pistons are connected like in the picture.I know the area of the big cylinder is 100 $cm^2$ while the one of the small cylinder is 50 $cm^2$ and that the pistons are tied by a rigid wire. There is air in both cylinders, initially having 27°C and normal pressure. The air in the smaller cylinder is heated, it's temperature increasing by 50°C. How much does the temperature of the air in the large cylinder need to increase so that the 2 pistons don't move.

If they stay in the same position, then they are in equilibrium, so the forces pushing against the 2 cylinders are equal + tension are equal (but we have $F_1+T=F_2+T$ so tension is eliminated and we remain with $F_1=F_2$, right ?)

From the formula for force I calculate that $p_1 \cdot 2S_2=p_2 \cdot S_2$
Then from Charles's law for the transformation in both cylinders I end up with $p_1=\frac{p_0 \cdot (300+x)}{300}$ and $p_2=\frac{p_0 \cdot (300+50)}{300}$ but calculating x gives me -125, so a change of 125°C  while the textbook says it should be 25°C

[image]

Comment: Only the increases in pressure matter, since the initial pressures are already balanced with the atmosphere.

Comment: Could you please ellaborate further ?

Comment: The net force acting on each of the pistons (zero at equilibrium) is the tension in the bar, the pressure force exerted by the atmosphere, and the pressure force exerted by the gas.  Use this to solve for the tension in the bar (or compressive force in the bar) imposed by each gas and the atmosphere.  Set the two values of tension equal.

Comment: @ChetMiller I appreciate your explanation, but could you put the mathematical equations as well ?. I think I don't grasp it super well, probably because it's pretty late where I live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treating the combination of the two pistons and the intervening rod as a free body, the equilibrium force balance is:  $$p_{g1}(2S_2)-p_0(2S_2)+p_0S_2-p_{g2}S_2=0$$where $p_0$ is the atmospheric pressure.  Initially, $p_{g1}=p_{g2}=p_0$ and finally $p_{g1}$ and $p_{g2}$ are given by the equations you wrote.  Writing the above equation in a slightly different form, we have:  $$(p_{g1}-p_0)(2S_2)=(p_{g2}-p_0)S_2$$